# Как сделать чтобы обьект двигался за персонажем?

Tags: unity3d

ну условно, у меня есть камера, и мне нужно чтобы она двигалась за персонажем в определенной точке и поварачивалась как нужно будто дочерня ему(меш при дочерности розтягивается) я это хотел сделать создав блок и чтобы камера перемещалась в центр блока, а блок дочерний обьекту, но камера вообще не реагирует и висит в небе, как сделать так?

Comment: не очень понятна суть вопроса, уточните пожалуйста проблему, опишите какие пути решения вы использовали, и прикрепите хотя бы минимально допустимый пример того что не так работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать очень грубо, прицепив камеру как дочерний объект к игроку и настроив его положение на определëнное расстояние

Но если хочешь сделать более красиво(и лучше, соответственно), то посмотри ролик

https://youtu.be/04EpnVbMKpU

Comment: спасибо, проблема в том что если камера дочерня ему то меш растягивается когда смотришь вверх либо вниз